# Math Expression in SELECT statement using JDBC/MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have written a MySQL query that uses joins and subqueries and finally gets the desired columns in the outermost `SELECT` statement. It goes something like:

```
SELECT X,Y,Z
FROM
(SELECT A,B,C,X 
FROM T1 
JOIN
(SELECT D,E,F,Y
FROM T2) ALIAS ON CONDITION....
```

and so on and so forth. Now, I wanted to do `Z/Y`, so I did

```
SELECT X,Y,Z,Z/Y
FROM
YADA YADA YADA
```

This works in MySQL, but when I did the same in a Java program, it throws an error, saying:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Z/Y'
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Table description and full statement are required.

Comment: There are about 5 joins. Everything is calculated in the subqueries, but the last value is a rate which depends on Y and Z. It works in MySQL, just not in Java JDBC.

Comment: It should work alright, but its hard to diagnose without seeing what query is actually making it to the server.  It could be that something  else has gone wrong, and your actual query isn't what you think it is.  See if you can log the actual query before it gets sent, or after the exception is thrown.

Comment: @CodingInCircles: The error message is from mySQL so it's likely that you have a typo in your query in java code.

Comment: It's something like `SELECT DC.Gross_Conversions AS 'Gross Conversions', SF.Net_Conv AS 'Net Conversions', (SF.Net_Conv/DC.Gross_Conversions)*100 AS 'Conversion Rate'` in MySQL. Copied word to word in Java. If I remove the last column, it works completely fine. Adding it is what screwed it up.

Comment: it al depends how you construct your SQL string. If you use a library like an HTML or XML parser they may escape your division operator `/` to a HTML or XML tag. Try to use the SQL string directly in your code and see what's happening

Comment: I'd forgotten the comma in the previous line of my query string in the program. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I had forgotten to add a comma to the penultimate column and it was causing the issue. Feel like a doofus!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are. And so am I. On the bright side, at least I got to reset the password on my oracle account.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class TwoAndTwo {
  private Connection connect = null;
  private Statement statement = null;
  private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
  private ResultSet resultSet = null;

  public void readDataBase() throws Exception {
    try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      connect = DriverManager
          .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/foobar?"
              + "user=root&password=root");

      statement = connect.createStatement();
      resultSet = statement
          .executeQuery("select 2+2 as computation");

      resultSet.next();
      System.out.println( resultSet.getString("computation"));
    } catch (Exception e) { throw e; } finally { close(); }
  }
  private void close() {
    try { if (resultSet != null) { resultSet.close(); }
      if (statement != null) { statement.close(); }
      if (connect != null) { connect.close(); }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace(); }
  }
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
      TwoAndTwo tnt = new TwoAndTwo();
      try { tnt.readDataBase();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}
```

## output

```
$ javac TwoAndTwo.java 

$ java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar:.  TwoAndTwo 
4
```